# on PlatformException catch is not working on version 2.2.2 of flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a SignIn method using firebase
this is my code which been working just fine

```
try {
      final auth = Provider.of<AuthBase>(context, listen: false);
      if (_formType == EmailSignInFormType.signIn) {
        await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(_email, _password);
      } else {
        await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(_email, _password);
      }
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    } catch (e) {
      PlatformAlertDialog(
        title: 'Sign in failed',
        content: e.toString(),
        defaultActionText: 'OK',
      ).show(context);
    }
```

and when I'm trying to improve my alert dialog by changing "catch (e)" to "on PlatformException catch (e)" with the same code as above, the exception handling brokes and the program stops working, when there is an exception.

I read the code of "PlatformException" and I figured out that it's not yet supporting null-safety and I'm guessing that this causes my problem, what do you think?

And is there any way to get the error message only using "catch (e)"

Comment: It sounds to me that what's being thrown and caught isn't actually a `PlatformException`.  What is `e.runtimeType`?

Comment: @jamesdlin 
its FirebaseAuthException
and I checked it using the first code
but when I'm trying to access the "catch" block while using "PlatformException catch (e)" it doesn't even enter it

Comment: Why would you expect it to? [`FirebaseAuthException`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth_platform_interface/latest/firebase_auth_platform_interface/FirebaseAuthException-class.html) does not derive from `PlatformException`.  Why not use `on FirebaseAuthException catch (e)`?

Comment: @jamesdlin It worked Thanks! , so the firebase exception is not considered as a platform exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by using `on FirebaseAuthException catch (e)` instead of `on PlatformException catch (e)`